# No Material Widget found textfield widgets require a material widget ancestor(Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am trying to build a login screen in flutter but I am getting below error when opening it.

No material widget found textfield widgets require a material widget ancestor

```html
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) =>
          context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
        ),
      ],
      child:MaterialApp(
        home: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 400,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/images/loginHeader.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FadeAnimation(
                            1.8,
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color:
                                        Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
                                        blurRadius: 20.0,
                                        offset: Offset(0, 10))
                                  ]),
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border(
                                            bottom: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.grey[100]))),
                                    child: TextField(
                                      controller: emailController,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          border: InputBorder.none,
                                          hintText: "Email or Phone number",
                                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey[400])),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: TextField(
                                      controller: passwordController,
                                      obscureText: true,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          border: InputBorder.none,
                                          hintText: "Password",
                                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey[400])),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          padding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100, top: 20, bottom: 20),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            gotoPatientList(BuildContext context) {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>PatientList()),
                              );
                            }
                            context.read<AuthenticationService>().signIn(
                              email: emailController.text.trim(),
                              password: passwordController.text.trim(),
                            );
                            gotoPatientList(context);
                          },
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27,1),
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Text("Login".toUpperCase(),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                        ),
                         Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),

                  ),
                        ClipOval(
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              gotoForgotPassword(BuildContext context) {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>ForgotPassword()),
                                );
                              }
                              gotoForgotPassword(context);
                            },
                            child: Text("Forgot Password"),
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            color:Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

In material design most widgets are conceptually printed on a sheet of material In flutter material library that material is represented by the Material widget that renders ink splashes

Comment: Try wrapping the code below MaterialApp with the Material widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the SingleChildScrollView in a Builder:

```
Builder(
builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView......
```

This is because the context you are using is not a child of MaterialApp.

A better solution will be to put MaterialApp in a widget MyApp for example, and use HomePage widget as home for the MaterialApp.
Also wrap the SingleChildScrollView inside Scaffold(body: SingleChild....